# What can python's asyncio do to improve this functionality?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

```
while True:
      if (len(queue) > 0):
            blocking_send_from_queue()
            there_is_something_to_send = False
      else:
            break
      data = non_blocking_recv()
      queue = process(queue, data)
```

This is code from a client, which is supposed to process queries.

To complete a query, it might have to create more sub-queries based on data received, and send them to the server, and then process the sub-queries' results, and so on.

Can I create more efficient or expanded results using asyncio?

Comment: That looks really prone to race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```py
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
data_queue = asyncio.Queue(loop=loop)
receiving = True

def forward(data):
    queue = process(queue, data)
    if (len(queue) > 0):
        blocking_send_from_queue()
        return True
    else:
        return False

async def receive():
    while receiving:
        data = await non_blocking_recv()
        await data_queue.put(data)

async def main():
    receiver = loop.create_task(receive())
    while True:
        data = await data_queue.get()
        if not await loop.run_in_executor(None, forward, data):
            global receiving
            receiving = False
            data_queue.get_no_wait()
            break
    await receiver

loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

So that, `non_blocking_recv()` and `blocking_send_from_queue()` could run in parallel without blocking each other, in the cost of buffering `data` blocks in memory with `data_queue`. You can set the queue size of `data_queue` to control the buffer size.

Furthermore, `process()` and `blocking_send_from_queue()` look like methods that can be executed in parallel. It depends on actual implementation, I assume `queue` is one persistent `threading.Queue` object here. Thus `forward` can be split into: (skipping the shutdown code)

```py
def do_process(data):
    process(queue, data)
    return len(queue) > 0

def forward():
    while True:
        blocking_send_from_queue()
```

And `main` shall be changed to:

```py
async def main():
    loop.create_task(receive())
    loop.run_in_executor(None, forward)
    while True:
        data = await data_queue.get()
        if not await loop.run_in_executor(None, do_process, data):
            break
```

Ideally, at most one `non_blocking_recv`, one `process` and one `blocking_send_from_queue` could run in parallel, if GIL is properly released within `blocking_send_from_queue`.

Finally, if GIL is even released in `process`, and if sending order is not required to be the same as receiving order, it is even possible to make full use of multi-core computing power, by running `process` in parallel: (partial code)

```py
async def process_worker():
    while True:
        data = await data_queue.get()
        loop.run_in_executor(None, process, queue, data)

async def main():
    loop.create_task(receive())
    loop.run_in_executor(None, forward)
    for _ in range(CPU_CORE_NUM):
        loop.create_task(process_worker())
    # wait for all tasks here
```